# django: drop down menu not displaying on template despite correct syntax

Tags: python, html, django, genome

I have successfully configured a way to upload files to a website that I am making. However we would like to include a drop-down menu on the site. However, we want to include in the form of a drop-down menu called "mismatch choice":

models.py: for drop-down menu

```
         class Mismatches(models.Model):
           MISMATCH_CHOICES = (
            ('0', '0'),
            ('1', '1'),
            ('2', '2'),
            ('3', '3'),
            )
           mismatch = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, default='0', choices = MISMATCH_CHOICES)
```

forms.py for drop-down menu:

```
          class MismatchesForm(ModelForm): #unsure how to reference a class in our in-app urls.py
            class Meta:
             model = Mismatches
             fields = ['mismatch']
```

'model=Mismatches' links to the Mismatches class in models and the 'field' gives the options.

views.py for drop-down menu

```
             class Mismatch_Choice(FormView):
               template_name = 'list.html'
               form_class = MismatchesForm
```

"template_name = 'list.html'" links the html page called list.html. 'form_class' links to the form 'MismatchesForm'.

html for drop-down menu

```
            <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
              {{ form.mismatch }}
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

We used a tutorial as a template for our code but it won't display on our html page even though we have referenced it with {{ form.mismatch}} which links to the variable 'mismatch' which is set in our form as the 'model' and hence links to the options given in models.py.

We are wondering if the html page is not seeing the drop-down menu because it's set as a class in the forms.py but we haven't referenced a class in our in-app urls.py (is there a way to do this?)...

Comment: Do you have any unapplied migrations? Does it show if you just do `{{ form }}`?

Comment: migrations applied: no it does not show....

Comment: I think something wrong with your choices, You have passes choices ('0', '0'), are string and field you have declared is integer - mismatch = models.IntegerField. This won't allow to save either you have to make choices int or field CharField.

Comment: ok thanks, we are using "IntegerField" at the bottom of models.py. mismatch = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, default='0', choices = MISMATCH_CHOICES)